# Is there a way I can center edittext input and floating label in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I want to apply white background to my EditText along TextInputLayout. However, when I do that, edittext input/hint seems to be at the bottom and I can understand that is because of the reserved space of floating label. However, I want my EditText to be in the center and when floating label comes, they both come to the center. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void addTextInputLayoutWatcher(TextInputLayout inputLayout) {

    EditText editText = inputLayout.getEditText();
    if (editText == null)
        return;

    float offset = inputLayout.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.inputlayout_focus_offset);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {

        float absY = initTag(inputLayout);

        if (hasFocus || editText.getText().length() > 0) {
            inputLayout.setY(absY + offset);
        } else {
            inputLayout.setY(absY);
        }
    });
}

private static float initTag(TextInputLayout inputLayout) {

    float absY;
    Object tag = inputLayout.getTag();

    if (tag == null) {
        // Setting for the first time
        absY = inputLayout.getY();
        inputLayout.setTag(absY);
    } else {
        absY = (float) tag;
    }

    return absY;
}
```

So, whenever the TextInputLayout has focus or is filled-in, give it that offset; otherwise reset it to the original position (which is saved in the view tag in the beginning).

You can set inputlayout_focus_offset to a value that is based on the height of the component, or it can be calculated in a more scaleable way. Either way, there's room for improvement there, but hopefully, this solution will set you off in the right direction.